# FreeBSD 12 on Poweredge T330 and Toshiba 12 TB SAS

Tags: freebsd, sasl

I am trying to add a SAS-disk (MG07SCA12TA) on Perc H330 to my server. When I try to initialize the disk with gpart `gpart create -s gpt mfisyspd4`, it yields `gpart: Input/output error`.

Here is what dmesg says:

```
mfisyspd4: hard error cmd=write fsbn 0
mfi0: I/O error, cmd=0xfffffe00006457e8, status=0x2e, scsi_status=0xf0
mfi0: sense error 0, sense_key 0, asc 0, ascq 0
```

`gpart show` lists:

```
=>        40  2929721264  mfisyspd4  GPT  (1.4T)
          40  2929721264             - free -  (1.4T)
```

Here is further up in dmesg:

```
mfisyspd4 on mfi0
mfisyspd4: 1430528MB (2929721344 sectors) SYSPD volume (deviceid: 4)
mfisyspd4:  SYSPD volume attached
mfi0: 936 (boot + 27s/0x0002/info) - Inserted: PD 20(c None/p1) Info: enclPd=20, scsiType=d, portMap=00, sasAddr=55cd90f00656d100,0000000000000000
mfi0: 937 (boot + 27s/0x0002/info) - Inserted: PD 00(e0x20/s0)
mfi0: 938 (boot + 27s/0x0002/info) - Inserted: PD 00(e0x20/s0) Info: enclPd=20, scsiType=0, portMap=01, sasAddr=4433221106000000,0000000000000000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the [mfi(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mfi&sektion=4) driver for the PERC H330 controller has problems with certain firmware versions (at least 25.3.0.0016 and 25.5.2.0001).

For that card it seems better to use the [mrsas(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mrsas&sektion=4) driver. There is a report of doubling the performance using `mrsas` over `mfi`.

You give priority to the `mrsas` driver with this setting in `/boot/device.hints`

```
hw.mfi.mrsas_enable="1"
```

From [Bug 239801](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=239801):

- mfi(4) can report I/O errors which is not related to an actual hardware failure
  after upgrading FreeBSD to 11.3 or 12.0.
- It seems that the I/O error depends on a specific firmware version.  Some older
  firmware versions work fine even with mfi(4) on 11.3 and 12.0.
- If the device is also supported by mrsas(4), switching to it will solves
  the error.  Note that it will cause an incompatibility issue---mfi(4) uses
  /dev/mfi* device nodes for the attached drives and mfiutil(8) as the userland
  utility.  mrsas(4) uses /dev/da* and a vendor-supplied utility such as
  megaCli instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll reinstall the OS tomorrow when I have a keyboard to connect to the server. Eager as I was, I put in the setting in the hint-file and forgot to modify the fstab, hence it wouldn't start.

Comment: Did you have better luck with the `mrsas` driver?

Comment: thanks for asking. I had to get it up and running fast, hence I had to resort to Ubuntu. I'll try to migrate to FreeBSD in the Christmas holidays. If I succeed, I'll do my best to remember to update this.

Comment: Hi Claus, finally I installed 12.2 and set the correct device hint to make mrsas the active driver and I can tell you it works as expected: identified the disks correctly (via dimesg) and they were mounted with the correct size. Thanks.